# Why can't I change the time for a date for less than ~29 minutes and why is the PHP time() and date() combo return a time that's ~27 minutes off?

Tags: php, date, time

So I have a block of PHP code, and I simply wanted to have a UNIX timestamp for the current date, and one that is 25 minutes earlier. The UNIX timestamp changes accordingly, but when I use each timestamp and convert it to a formatted date with the date('M d, Y A -- h:m:s',$current) or date('M d, Y A -- h:m:s',$old), both times turn out exactly the same. It seems a change greater than 29 minutes works, but I'm not sure why. And the second part of the question: with using time() and date() and even setting the timezone to my own, the time it returns is about 20-30 minutes behind, and this also concerns me.

```
<?

date_default_timezone_set('MST');

$current = time();
$old = time() - (25 * 60);

echo $current . ' - ' . $old; // Prints 1330473445 - 1330471945
echo date('h:m:s A -- M d, Y',$current); // 04:02:25 PM -- Feb 28, 2012
echo date('h:m:s A -- M d, Y', $old); // 04:02:25 PM -- Feb 28, 2012

?>
```

This is how it prints on my screen. Different UNIX timestamps, but same formatted date. And I suppose you mean system clock as in the one I need to edit via BIOS. As far as the clock on my computer is concerned, that's what I was comparing it to.

### Update

Solved. Used an 'm' for seconds rather than the 'i'

Comment: Can you post some relevant code?  `time()` just returns the time from the system clock, so if its off by about 20-30 minutes, then the system clock is probably off too.  Correcting the time on the system should fix that issue.  As for the other problem with old and new being the same, we will have to see the code to reproduce it.  Oh, Welcome to SO!

Comment: stackoverflow is about programming, programming is about programs, programs are about code, now guess what you should post to receive an answer.

Comment: Post your code, your question sounds really wired. At least with the code it might become more clear. And please see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem solved nice and fast XD Albeit I feel like an idiot after using the `h:m:s` all this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you used "h:m:s"

```
echo date("M d, Y A -- h:i:s",$ut); and your problem is solved
```

m is not "minutes" m = month
i = minutes

I know it's evil, I just fell for it myself for a while ;)
Here the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Comment: Thank you .-. But now I feel like a complete and utter idiot XD

Comment: No problem, it's something that likely happens to most people using date() in PHP sooner or later.

Comment: you should set my answer as "accepted" so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

what does this give you:

```
<?php

echo $current.' - '.$old;

?>
```

you can also use strtotime('-25 minutes') as your second argument.

Also, I think you mean `i` not `m` for minutes.  This is using month not minutes.  Try with `i` instead and see if that works?

Comment: `<?
date_default_timezone_set('MST');
$current = time();
$old = time() - (25 * 60);
echo $current . ' - ' . $old; // Prints: 1330473000 - 1330471500
?>`

Comment: btw, how the hell do I retain the white space? O.o